# Fundamental Group of complement of Integers

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X=\mathbb{R}\times (-1,1)-\mathbb{Z}\times \{0\}$.  I want to compute the fundamental group of that space.

I would be tempted to do some division like the following to apply Van Kampen, but to do it all the sets must intersect in the basepoint of $\pi(X,x)$, so I can't really do it. 
[image]
If I incorrectly use Van Kampen, I will get to the correct result that it's free in a countable number of generators, though.

Is there any other way to do that, I mean, with the basic theory of Hatcher's of Massey's book (It's an exercise from Massey's book)?

Comment: Not exactly. The problem is the use of the ideas from Topology and Groupoids, which I don't really know about, and this is just an exercise from Massey's book.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978851/is-the-plane-minus-the-integer-lattice-homeomorphic-to-the-plane-minus-the-integ

Comment: Why not just add $\mathbb R\times(\frac12,1)$ to each of your $B_i$s and declare the basepoint to be $(0,\frac34)$?

Comment: It is curious to me that standard algebraic  topology with its choice of a single base point is willing to take elaborate steps to avoid dealing with connected spaces. I refer you to comments of Grothendieck given in Engllsh at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220561/descent-theorems-for-fundamental-groups-and-groupoids .  Why give students a version of the van Kampen theorem which does not compute the fundamental group of the circle?

Comment: My previous comment should replace "connected" by "nonconnected"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to proceed as follows. Define $Y = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} S(n)$, where $S(n) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \lVert x - n \rVert =  \frac{1}{2}) \}$. This is an infinite chain of circles. It is easy to see that $Y$ is a strong deformation retract of $X$. Now $Y$ has the structure of a CW-complex, $0$-cells being the sets $\{n - \frac{1}{2} \}$ and $1$-cells being the upper and lowers half circles of the $S(n)$. Then $Y_0 = Y \cap \mathbb{R} \times (1,0]$ is subcomplex of $Y$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, $Y_0$ is contractible. It is known that then $p : Y \to Y/Y_0$ is a homotopy equivalence. But $Y/Y_0$ is nothing else than a countably infinite wedge of circles and your arguments apply.

Comment: Yes. I was just thinking about something similar, trying to collapse the maximal tree of that graph, which translates in what you did.

Answer (score 3):

Use Van Kampen inductively to prove that for all $n$ the set $X_n = B_{-n} \cup \cdots \cup B_n$ is free of rank $2n+1$, and that the inclusion $X_n \to X_{n+1}$ takes the rank $2n+1$ free group $\pi_1(X_n)$ to a free factor of the rank $2n+3$ free group $\pi_1(X_{n+1})$. Then use a direct limit argument to conclude that $\pi_1(\cup_{n=1}^\infty X_n)$ is free of infinite rank.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say a [rose of countably infinitely many petals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(topology));  but I'm not sure it's correct.  At least it seems like it might deformation retract onto it...

Comment: Yes, a rose (or a boquet of circles) is the same as a wedge of circles. But I do not see how we could get a closed embedding.of an infinite rose into $X$.

Comment: But we can define a map from an infinite rose to $X$ which is a homotopy equivalence!

Comment: @PaulFrost I suspected as much.